# Can't connect to MySQL DB with Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, access-denied

I set up my database server a while ago and had my node web server connecting to it fine. In my dbcommon.js file I have the following.

```
var credentials = require('./db_access');
var mysql = require('mysql');

//Use this function to grab a thread from the db thread pool and connect to the db.  Then it queries the db with the sql statement passed to it.
exports.executeStatement = function(pool, sql, callback){
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        }
        else {  
            connection.query(sql, function(err, results, fields) {
                if(!err){
                    connection.release();
                    callback(results);

                } else {
                    connection.release();
                    callback(err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};

//TODO - Own class
exports.pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: "host_url_goes_here",
    user: credentials.user,
    password: credentials.pass,
    database: "bxdb",
    dateStrings: true //Instead of converting to a JS Date object, return as a string
});
```

In my db_access.js file I have

```
var user = 'user123';
var pass = 'password123'; //not real

module.exports = user;
module.exports = pass;
```

The strange thing was this working absolutely fine until I decided to try and use IAM keys to access the database instead. However I couldn't get this to work (access denied error) so I changed back to what I have now and yet I still get an access denied error. Yet my friend who has the same code is still able to access the database without getting this error. I am very confused. The db_access.js file is in the same folder as the dbcommon.js file.

Also, is the way I'm currently accessing the database reasonably secure? Or should I be doing it another way? (The db_access.js file is never pushed to git it is only available locally)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying my mates db_access file over to my directory and it worked. Not sure what the problem was because I checked about 10 times for misspellings and syntax errors etc. Could've been a weird char messing things up like a smart quote or something.